# Perl counting with regex and variables

Tags: regex, perl, variables, count, match

i'm writing perl script to find out unused variables within some code.
I was able to get the entire function body and names of all variables within this function.

I'd like now to count appearance of each variable within function body (if it has appeared only 1, this is unused variable, otherwise it's ok).

Comments from function body are removed to avoid bug-counts.

```
foreach my $var (@vars) {                   # @vars is an array of all variables name
                                            # $fun_body is function body (string)
    my $count = $fun_body =~ tr/\Q$var//;   # this line is tricky and does not work
    print $count." : ".$var."\n";
}
```

Rigth now i'm getting some useless info from my script:

```
1046 : v_result
1046 : v_LastValue
1046 : v_LastValue_2
```

It looks like script does not use variable as an input to regex, but uses `$var` as a string. Optimization is not what i'm going for or i'll go for it when script will be working properly (code to be parsed is relatively small, it has 100k - 500k lines).

My Question is:
Has any1 got an idea how to count with regex that uses variable?.

Answer (score 2):

From [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string?) (How can I count the number of occurrences of a substring within a string?):

> This is fine if you are just looking for a single character. However,
>   if you are trying to count multiple character substrings within a
>   larger string, tr/// won't work.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $fun_body = 'foo bar baz foo goo hoo';
my @vars = qw(foo bar);
for my $var (@vars) {
    $var = quotemeta $var;
    my $count = () = $fun_body =~ /\b$var\b/g;
    print "$var: $count\n";
}

__END__

foo: 2
bar: 1
```

Comment: You are not taking into acount that his variables will have a sigil like `$`, which is a meta-character in regex. Thus, you are not escaping it. This will not work for the OP.

Comment: The OP did not specify what language is being parsed.  If it is `C`, there are no sigils.  You should pose this as a question for the OP.

Comment: That's right, but he used `\Q` in his code, so that suggests he is aware that might happen.

Comment: I'm not using sigil, this language is based on C (company internal language) and my variables are following C naming convention.

This solution works more then fine. This is what i was going for :) many thx toolic!

Answer (score 1):

The [`B::Xref`](https://metacpan.org/module/B%3a%3aXref) module will show you all the information you could want regarding identifier definition and usage within a program.

Use it like

```
perl -MO=Xref myprog.pl
```